# Can we edit our review for Low Quality Post?

Tags: feature-request, review

I accidently set "Looks OK" review to one of the low quality post.

**Can we edit our review in such case?**
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately no, however, you can flag the answer again to let other members review and take the correct decision!